# How to enable a disabled button if a condition is met in vue.js?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-component

I have a 'submit' button that I've currently set to disabled under van-submit-bar. I need it to be enabled once the user selects a table number from the drop down options.

- By default the select table is the first option in the drop down, so that's why I have the submit button disabled.
- Once the user has chosen a table, the user will be able to select the 'submit' button. I've pasted what the option list looks like below.

This is the submit button;

```
<van-submit-bar
      :price="toPrice(basketTotalPrice)"
      disabled
      label="Total:"
      currency="£"
      button-text="Submit"
      :loading="isLoading"
      @submit="onSubmit"
    >
```

This is the select table dropdown option;

```
   <div v-bind:style="style"></div>
    <van-dropdown-menu direction="up">
    <van-dropdown-item v-model="value1" :options="option1" />
    </van-dropdown-menu>



option1: [
            { text: 'Select Table', value: 0 },
            { text: 'Table 1', value: 1 },
            { text: 'Table 2', value: 2 },
            { text: 'Table 3', value: 3 },
```

Seems like it should be an easy thing to do, but I'm having some trouble.

Thanks

Comment: Please create a minimal example.

Comment: Can you add your vue code?

Comment: Added to the original post

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can utilize Vue's reactivity to do this pretty easily. Without seeing your code all I can provide is a common approach.

**In your template**

```
<select v-model="selectData">...</select>
<button :disabled="!selectData">Action</button>
```

**Then in your script**

```
data () {
    return {
      selectData: null,
    }
  },
```

This will cause the value to start out empty and when the select list is changed the `v-model` will update and enable the button.

Answer (score 1):

You can toggle the element's disabled property like this:

- Boolean - `:disabled="true"`  or `"disabled="false"`
- Variable - `:disabled="yourVariable"`
- Function - `:disabled="yourFunc(arg)"`

Your code will end up looking like this:

```
<van-submit-bar
      :price="toPrice(basketTotalPrice)"
      :disabled="yourVariable" // <-- You can use a variable or call a function must be a boolean value
      label="Total:"
      currency="£"
      button-text="Submit"
      :loading="isLoading"
      @submit="onSubmit"
    >
```

Comment: But how do I enable it not to be disabled? If its disabled by default and then not disabled once the other drop down has been selected.

Comment: @CalumPrice if you set `:disabled` equal to a boolean variable, then you can change that variable's value based on the dropdown having a selected value.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working by adding;

```
<van-submit-bar
  :price="toPrice(basketTotalPrice)"
  label="Total:"
  currency="£"
  button-text="Submit"
  :loading="isLoading"
  **:disabled="!selectedTable"**
  @submit="onSubmit"
>
```

and adding **selectedTable: 0,** to my data() section